# Pitcher awarded the winning record

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

In an MLB game, Astros' pitcher left the game in top of 5th while the Astros were winning 7-6. They since used a new pitcher in every inning. At the end the Astros won the game 8-6. Which pitcher gets the winning record?

Comment: Do you know what was the date of the game?

Comment: According to https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/HOU/HOU201709030.shtml, Will Harris was awarded the win. Are you asking *why* that is the case? If I had to guess, I would say the official scorer felt that he did a better job of preserving the lead than Tyler Clippard (who allowed an inherited runner to score).